# how to copy postgresql gitlab database via FTP on ubuntu

Tags: ftp, postgresql, gitlab

Hi I would like to copy my old database of *[gitlab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab)* to a new server but my old server is working only as FTP server.

Can I copy the old *gitlab* database to a new server via ftp ?